# Trying to draw an image in a 2d graphics but it wont work

Tags: java, swing

I want to add an image in the top left corner of the `JFrame` but it won't appear there. I've tried changing the `Image` into a `BufferedImage` and `ImageIcon` but I don't know if I was doing it correctly.

Here's the code:

```
public class Board {
static Font font;
Board(){
    try { font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("AlphaRomaineFont.ttf"));
    }
    catch(IOException | FontFormatException e){

    }
}
public static JFrame createNewBoard(){
    JFrame screen = new JFrame();
    screen.setUndecorated(true);
    screen.setFont(font);
    screen.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(720,720));
    screen.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    screen.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight()));
    screen.setVisible(true);
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.setBackground(Color.decode("#ebe4e4"));
    screen.setVisible(true);
    screen.setResizable(false);

    Map<Integer, Character> x_AxisMap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
    x_AxisMap.put(0, 'a');
    x_AxisMap.put(1, 'b');
    x_AxisMap.put(2, 'c');
    x_AxisMap.put(3, 'd');
    x_AxisMap.put(4, 'e');
    x_AxisMap.put(5, 'f');
    x_AxisMap.put(6, 'g');
    x_AxisMap.put(7, 'h');

    Map<Integer, Character> y_AxisMap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
    y_AxisMap.put(0, '8');
    y_AxisMap.put(1, '7');
    y_AxisMap.put(2, '6');
    y_AxisMap.put(3, '5');
    y_AxisMap.put(4, '4');
    y_AxisMap.put(5, '3');
    y_AxisMap.put(6, '2');
    y_AxisMap.put(7, '1');

    
    JPanel board = new JPanel(){
        boolean color = true;
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics graphic){
            graphic.setFont(new Font("AlphaRomaineFont.ttf", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
                for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
                    if(color){
                        graphic.setColor(Color.decode("#f5f1e6"));
                    }
                    else if(!color){
                        graphic.setColor(Color.decode("#449e48"));
                    }
                    graphic.fillRect(x*(screen.getWidth()/8), y*(screen.getHeight()/8), screen.getWidth()/8, screen.getHeight()/8);

                    if(y == 7){
                        graphic.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        graphic.drawString(String.valueOf(x_AxisMap.get(x)), x*(screen.getWidth()/8)+3,  y*(screen.getHeight()/8)+87);
                        if(color){
                            graphic.setColor(Color.decode("#f5f1e6"));
                        }
                        else if(!color){
                            graphic.setColor(Color.decode("#449e48"));
                        }
                    }

                    if(x == 7){
                        graphic.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        graphic.drawString(String.valueOf(y_AxisMap.get(y)), x*(screen.getWidth()/8)+80,  y*(screen.getHeight()/8)+15);
                        if(color){
                            graphic.setColor(Color.decode("#f5f1e6"));
                        }
                        else if(!color){
                            graphic.setColor(Color.decode("#449e48"));
                        }
                    }
                    if(x == 0){
                        if(y == 0){
                            Image piece = Piece.Rook.getWhiteRook();
                            graphic.drawImage(piece, x*(screen.getWidth()/8), y*(screen.getWidth()/8), this);
                        }
                    }
                    color = !color;
                }
                color = !color;
            }
        } 
    };
    board.setBounds(0, 0, screen.getWidth(), screen.getHeight());     
    
    screen.add(board);
    return screen;
}
private static int getScreenWidth() {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    return screenSize.width;
}
private static int getScreenHeight() {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    return screenSize.height;
}
```

}

and

```
public static final class Rook extends Piece{
    Rook(){

    }

    public static Image getWhiteRook(){
        Image image = null;
        try{
            image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("75_px_white_rook.png");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return image;
    }
    public Image getBlackRook(){
        Image image = null;
        try{
            image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("75_px_black_rook.png");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return image;
    }
}}
```

The problem piece of code is: (in the Board Class)

```
 if(x == 0){
    if(y == 0){
      Image piece = Piece.Rook.getWhiteRook();
      graphic.drawImage(piece, x*(screen.getWidth()/8), y*(screen.getWidth()/8), this);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Change `catch(IOException | FontFormatException e){ }` to `catch(IOException | FontFormatException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }` then if the output is not enough to help you solve it, [edit] the question to add that stack trace and a [mre].

Comment: Prefer paintComponent over paint; call super.paintXxx first; prefer layout managers

Comment: Prefer `ImageIO` over `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer overriding `paintComponent` over `paint`.  You should also call `super.paintXxx` before doing any custom painting.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details.

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` in this context, is a bad idea.  It doesn't take into account other system assets, like task/menus/docks.  Make use of [`JFrame#setExtendedState`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)) instead.

Using `screenSize` to do things like `graphic.fillRect(x*(screen.getWidth()/8), y*(screen.getHeight()/8), screen.getWidth()/8, screen.getHeight()/8);` is also a bad idea.  Instead, you should be looking at the actual size of the component.

You also want to decouple your workflows, in such away as they are more easily re-usable.  This would mean (for me), making the `Board` class a `JPanel` and using it as the base component, rather then creating a custom `JPanel` within it.

Prefer [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) over `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(...)`.  Lots of reasons why, but primarily, `ImageIO` will actually throw an exception if the image can't be loaded.  `ImageIO` also doesn't use a background thread to load the image, so once it returns successfully, you know you have a fully realised image.

Also, `Toolkit#getImage(String)` accepts a "file" on the file system.  This is the single greatest cause of issues.  The "working" directory of the app may not be the "installed" directory of the app, so unless you know exactly where on the disk the image is (and using absolute files paths have their own issues), this is going to cause you problems.

Instead, embed the resources within the application context.  Different IDEs/build systems do this differently, for example Netbeans and Eclipse (when not using Maven) will allow you to drop resources directly into the `src` folder. This will be made available to your application at runtime, via `Class#getResource`.

So, to "answer" your question, I would add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` to your code and check the actually running location of your application.  I'd then check the return result of `Piece.Rook.getWhiteRook()` (ie `System.out.println(Piece.Rook.getWhiteRook());`) to see if it's `null` or not.

Then I'd embed the resource instead.

## Runnable example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Piece.loadResources();
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new Board());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to load resources", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class Board extends JPanel {        
        private Map<Integer, Character> x_AxisMap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
        private Map<Integer, Character> y_AxisMap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();

        public Board() {
            setBackground(Color.decode("#ebe4e4"));
            x_AxisMap.put(0, 'a');
            x_AxisMap.put(1, 'b');
            x_AxisMap.put(2, 'c');
            x_AxisMap.put(3, 'd');
            x_AxisMap.put(4, 'e');
            x_AxisMap.put(5, 'f');
            x_AxisMap.put(6, 'g');
            x_AxisMap.put(7, 'h');

            y_AxisMap.put(0, '8');
            y_AxisMap.put(1, '7');
            y_AxisMap.put(2, '6');
            y_AxisMap.put(3, '5');
            y_AxisMap.put(4, '4');
            y_AxisMap.put(5, '3');
            y_AxisMap.put(6, '2');
            y_AxisMap.put(7, '1');
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(720, 720);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            boolean color = true;
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    if (color) {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.decode("#f5f1e6"));
                    } else if (!color) {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.decode("#449e48"));
                    }
                    g2d.fillRect(x * (getWidth() / 8), y * (getHeight() / 8), getWidth() / 8, getHeight() / 8);

                    if (y == 7) {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(x_AxisMap.get(x)), x * (getWidth() / 8) + 3, y * (getHeight() / 8) + 87);
                        if (color) {
                            g2d.setColor(Color.decode("#f5f1e6"));
                        } else if (!color) {
                            g2d.setColor(Color.decode("#449e48"));
                        }
                    }

                    if (x == 7) {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(y_AxisMap.get(y)), x * (getWidth() / 8) + 80, y * (getHeight() / 8) + 15);
                        if (color) {
                            g2d.setColor(Color.decode("#f5f1e6"));
                        } else if (!color) {
                            g2d.setColor(Color.decode("#449e48"));
                        }
                    }
                    if (x == 0) {
                        if (y == 0) {
                            Image piece = Piece.ROOK.white();
                            g2d.drawImage(piece, x * (getWidth() / 8), y * (getWidth() / 8), this);
                        }
                    }
                    color = !color;
                }
                color = !color;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum Piece {
        ROOK;

        private Image white;
        private Image black;

        public Image white() {
            return white;
        }

        public Image black() {
            return black;
        }

        public static void loadResources() throws IOException {
            Piece.ROOK.white = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource("/images/RookWhite.png"));
            Piece.ROOK.black = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource("/images/RookBlack.png"));
        }
    }
}
```

*nb: Obviously I'm using different image names, so you'll need to correct for that*